# Oracle NUMTODSINTERVAL function and interval function

Tags: oracle

Can someone please explain what the below is doing?

```
and effective_DATE < (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(EXTRACT(DAY FROM TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE)), 'DAY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

I don't have access to the database so can not run it myself to test.

What I understand is that the NUMTODSINTERVAL converts a number to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND literal.

So say if I ran this query today it would check to see if the effective date is less than the 5th of Feb 2019 - 5 days converted to seconds plus 1 day?

So, 5th Feb - 000000005 + 1 = 6th Feb?

Is this correct or am I looking at this wrong?
Also why would developers use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to NUMTODSINTERVAL specifies the unit. "INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND" is a confusing name - it just means an abstract interval of time, in this case 5 days.

`EXTRACT(DAY FROM TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE))` finds the current day of the month (5 today)
`NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'DAY')` creates an INTERVAL of +5 days

So today it's saying, take Feb 5, subtract 5 days (which = Jan 31), then add one day (so Feb 1).

It seems to be trying to find the first day of the month, which would be much simpler as:

```
 and effective_DATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM')
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Yeah it seems overly complex so I think that's why I was so confused